# JPopupMenu that automatically resizes as I write in the JTextField inside

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, jpopupmenu

I'm trying to build a `JPopupMenu` that appears on mouse entering in a specific component. This `JPopupMenu` contains a `JTextField` for value editing (numbers). Since I cannot know in advance the length of the number that will be edited, I'd like to make my popup resizing after each key is typed. I achieved this by adding KeyListener to the `JTextField` and trying to handle the focus. My trick works, but I meet the following problems when I build the application:

- Every time I call the `pack()` method, the focus moves from `JtextField` to another component and then comes back to `JtextField` thanks to the `requestFocus()` method (this makes my windows continuously flickering). In this case, to make the other component not focusable could not be a solution to me.
- `JPopupMenu` disappears when its size so as to exit from the window.

I attach an abstract of my code below.
Is there a better way to achieve my goal? Or to manage the issues caused by the use of both `pack()` and `requestFocus()` methods?

```
package prova;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {
    public final static void main(String[] args ){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100,100));

        JLabel l = new JLabel("my label");
        l.setOpaque(true);
        l.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50,20));
        l.setBackground(Color.white);

        JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();

        JTextField textField = new JTextField("edit text");
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                pop.pack();
                ((JTextField)e.getSource()).requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        });



        l.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                if(!pop.isVisible()){
                    pop.show((java.awt.Component)e.getSource(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        });

        pop.add(textField);
        p.add(l,BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the first problem:**

Solution:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(pop);
    window.pack();
}
```

I think(!) the reason for the flicker effect is because `JPopupMenu` doesn't extend `Window` in it's class hierarchy (see below), and the `pack()` method is designed for windows only.

```
 java.lang.Object
    java.awt.Component
        java.awt.Container
            javax.swing.JComponent
                javax.swing.JPopupMenu
```

**For the second problem:**

I don't understand what you mean by that, the popupmenu doesn't disappear for me when it's size is "too big" (if that is what you meant).

Comment: Thank you very much! window.pack() perfectly works. I believe that the second problem was a matter of loosing focus but, anyway, it doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: theoretically and practically wrong answer 1. JTextField should be listened from DocumentListener, 2. and any event to the Top-Level Container should be wrapped into invokeLater, 3. JPopup isn't good container, by default isn't container, 4. to use JWindow(caveat - JTextField /inside JWindow/ without JFrame as parent isn't editable) or undecorated JDialog with proper ModalityType